# Webpack - How to set hot-reload (watch files)

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, livereload

I'm new to webpack and I am having trouble setting up how to make webpack watch my files as I change things in my code. **In other words, I would like to have the page reloads everytime I make a change in my code.**

I've read couple blogs on how to do it but I cannot seem to make it work.
As of current I am able to bundle it and host it on my localhost with out a problem.

Here's what I have so far:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  watch: true,
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "simple-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "demo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you don't need to include `node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js`. You can just do `"start": "webpack-dev-server"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out what I needed to using `react-hot-loader` if anyone is interested

http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/